# Mapeando de forma genérica múltiplas faixas numéricas

Tags: c, matemática, range, microcontrolador

Estou escrevendo um código, para tomada de decisões em um microcontrolador 8bits, um AVR.

Recebo 8 faixa de valores double, limitadas por Vf_max e Vf_min, não sei qual será o maior em cada faixa.
Como no exemplo abaixo, percebe-se que são coordenadas distribuídas em seus quadrantes:

```
const double LIMIT_NORTE[]    = {  -1,   1};   // 0x14
const double LIMIT_NORDESTE[] = {   1,  89};   // 0x11
const double LIMIT_LESTE[]    = {  89,  91};   // 0x12
const double LIMIT_SUDESTE[]  = {  91, 179};   // 0x22
const double LIMIT_SUL[]      = { 179, 180};   // 0x23
const double LIMIT_SUDOESTE[] = {-180, -91};   // 0x33
const double LIMIT_OESTE[]    = { -91, -89};   // 0x34
const double LIMIT_NOROESTE[] = { -89,  -1};   // 0x44
```

Sendo assim, eu recebendo um valor por exemplo 45, sei que este valor está no primeiro quadrante  e equivale a faixa Nordeste, 1 a 89, se eu receber um valor por exemplo -130, sei que está no sudoeste, e assim por diante.

Porém preciso converter tal valor recebido em porcento da faixa que ele pertence, e não estou conseguindo achar uma formula que viabilize tal conversão de forma geral, já que, no programa, tais faixas podem mudar quando parametrizado, ou seja os limites do que se considera a faixa Sul, podem ser ampliados, reduzindo os limites do sudeste e sudoeste.

Por exemplo recebendo 45 sei intuitivamente que será 50% da faixa Nordeste.

Alguém pode me ajudar com uma fórmula genérica para tal calculo? Lembrando a função map() amplamente divulgada no Arduino não funciona, e já tentei o que está proposto em https://stackoverflow.com/a/5732390/2766598

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regra_de_tr%C3%AAs_simples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que o intervalos são semi-abertos [min, max), você pode resolver esse problema com o seguinte algoritmo genérico:

```
//pseudo-código

intervalo encontra_intervalo(valor) {
  para cada possível intervalo i {
    se valor >= i.min ou valor < i.max
      retorne i
  }
}

double calcula_porcentagem(valor, min, max) {
  tamanho_intervalo = abs(max + (min * -1))
  valor_truncado = abs(valor + (min * -1))
  valor_normalizado = valor_truncado / tamanho_intervalo
  retorne valor_normalizado
}
```

Para cada valor primeiro busque em qual intervalo ele se encontra, com as informações do intervalo calcule o valor normalizado para o intervalo selecionado.